# How to get the value of text node inside <div> element using XPATH and Jtidy

Tags: java, xpath

I have been banging my head over for two days now.
I have a XHTML web-page from which i want to scrap some data 
I am using JTidy to DOMParse and then XPathFactory to find nodes using XPath

The Xhtml snippet is something like this

```
    <div style="line-height: 22px;" id="dvTitle" class="titlebtmbrdr01">BAJAJ AUTO LTD.</div>
```

Now i want that BAJAJ AUTO LTD.

The code that i am using is :

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.Vector;

    import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

     import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


   public class BSEQuotesExtractor implements valueExtractor {

@Override
public Vector<String> getName(Document d) throws XPathExpressionException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//div[@id='dvTitle']/text()");
    Object result = expr.evaluate(d, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList)result;
    for(int i=0;i<nodes.getLength();i++)
    {
        System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
    }

    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, XPathExpressionException{
    BSEQuotesExtractor q = new BSEQuotesExtractor();
    DOMParser parser = new DOMParser(new URL("http://www.bseindia.com/bseplus/StockReach/StockQuote/Equity/BAJAJ%20AUTO%20LTD/BAJAJAUT/532977/Scrips").openStream());
    Document d = parser.getDocument();
    q.getName(d);

}

    }
```

But i gett a null output and not BAJAJ AUTO LTD.
Please rescue me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//div[@id='dvTitle']");
Object result = expr.evaluate(d, XPathConstants.NODE);
Node node = (Node)result;
System.out.println(node.getTextContent());
```

Answer (score 1):

you must use `XPathConstants.STRING` instead of `XPathConstants.NODESET`.
You want to get a value of a single element (div), not a list of nodes.
Write:

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
String divContent = (String) path.evaluate("//div[@id='dvTitle']", document, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

Into `divContent` you get "BAJAJ AUTO LTD.".

Comment: Very strange. If you have Firebug open the console and evaluate this expression $x("//div[@id='dvTitle'] on your html page to test if the XPath is correct.

Comment: i guess, the elements have no text value,nut then in DOM we have only elements